# How to match an element with data clicked in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to create a modal that will display all the data on the element clicked.
For exemple, if i clicked the id(367) of a movie, it will display the title, the genres and the released date.

Comment: can you please some code so that it will be easier to help .

Answer (score 0):

First i created a Context.js that will send data in the component Movie.js:

Context.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { getAxios } from "../Function/index";
const MovieContext = createContext();

const MovieProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const [testdatas, testsetDatas] = useState([]);

  const getMovie = async () => {
    const data = await getAxios(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key={}"
    );
    setDatas(data.results);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getMovie();
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <MovieContext.Provider value={{ datas, testdatas }}>{children}</MovieContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { MovieContext, MovieProvider };
```

Movie.js

```
  import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { MovieContext } from '../Context'
import { Card, Row, Tag } from 'antd'


const Main = () => {
  const { datas } = useContext(MovieContext)
  return (
    <Row gutter={16}>
      {datas.map((item, id) => (
        <Card
          key={id}
          style={{ width: 300, margin: 10 }} bordered={true}
          hoverable
        >
          <div>
            <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>{item.title} <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{item.vote_average}</span></p>
          </div>
          <p><img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${item.poster_path}`} alt="#" width="200" height="200" /></p>
          <Tag color="red"> {item.title}</Tag>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </Row >
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: With an `onClick`-handler, you can pass your `item`-object for example to a state, which will be consumed by your actual Modal-component. Since you don't describe your question really well (do you have problems invoking a modal?), it's hard to answer.

Comment: In fact, i am looking for to display a modal that will not show the same data when i have clicked several different id.